# django uwsgi - "No module named 'project'"

Tags: django, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up a Dockerised django/uwsgi stack.

When I start the containers, uWSGI logs a "*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'*".

I'm obviously doing something dumb, but I can't see what.

Following the guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/#configuring-and-starting-the-uwsgi-server-for-django), my dir tree looks like:

```
mysite
    docker-compose.yml
    manage.py
    project
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        settings
            __init__.py
            base.py
            local.py
```

The django docker container mounts the entire `mysite` dir as `/mysite`.

My uwsgi INI file contains:

```
chdir = /mysite/project
module = project.wsgi:application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.local
```

(I've also tried with `chdir = /mysite`)

What simple and obvious mistake am I making here?

Comment: You project suppose to be `mysite`, so try with `chdir = /mysite/`, please try that again and provide the uwsgi logs. You can also use `pythonpath=/mysite/` to indicate Python to consider your project as a start point to find modules

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I think I'd just mucked up the syntax somewhere. I dropped and recreated the entire `project` dir (via `django-admin startproject project .`) and everything is running as expected now.